# How to read the Lookup column value using JS/Jquery?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jquery, jsom, js

One of the Projects I am working on, I have a requirement to read the lookup column Value in a document library while uploading a document.

For example, if someone uploads a document to the SharePoint library, they will select a value in the lookup field(mandatory) and once they hit on Save/CheckIn to save document in the library, it should alert  with the lookup value that user chose.

Please let me know, how to achieve this using JSOM approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add the custom jQuery code in the default edit form like the picture below. And edit the default edit form, add the script web part and add the custom jQuery code in the script web part.

[image]

There is a demo.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ctl40_g_208827b4_894c_4842_bbdf_f311bae2ed4a_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").click(function () {
            var value = $("select[title='look1 Required Field']").find("option:selected").text();
            alert(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result as below, when I click the “check in”, it will alert the selected value in lookup column.

[image]

There is a similar post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/529ee28f-80bf-44a6-9cb4-392e74213076/how-to-get-value-from-lookup-field-on-onchange-event?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

To change the name of the file as the “Name and lookup column value”, you could refer to the demo below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var look1 = $("select[title='look1 Required Field']").find("option:selected").val();
    var name = $("input[title='Name Required Field']").val();
    $("input[title='Name Required Field']").val(name+" "+look1);

    $("select[title='look1 Required Field']").change(function(){
        $("input[title='Name Required Field']").val(name+" "+$(this).find("option:selected").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

The result as below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a bunch, I will try this and get back to you if it works and will mark it as answer as well.

Comment: thanks so much. That worked like a charm. I had one additional question, now that I am able to read the Entity ID with your help. Is it possible to rename the file name while upload. I want to append Entity ID (lookup column, from where I am reading the field value) at the end of the file name. Let's say the user uploads a document named 'Test Doc' and then if a user selects lookup column value and clicks on CheckIN, then I would want to rename the File name as 'Test Doc'+lookup column value which we are alerting so something like Test Doc 46. Note 46 is the value.

Comment: I have updated my reply.